# Get a list of tables filtered by labels in BigQuery using Java client library

Tags: java, google-bigquery, label

I'm using BigQuery's Java client library. May I ask if there is a way to specify labels when getting the list of BigQuery tables, so that the tables I get are already filtered by the labels I specified? The following example can't specify labels.

[link](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/blob/65ca2f3d03d2744f59e5d4109c4efebe998a9514/google-cloud-examples/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/examples/bigquery/snippets/BigQuerySnippets.java#L269)

Answer (score 0):

As of today, as explained in the documentation for [working with BigQuery lab](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-managing-labels#filtering_datasets_using_labels),  this option is not possible:

> Currently, you cannot list tables or views based on a filter
>   specification.

In any case, the BigQuery team is already aware that this is an interesting feature for some use cases, given that there is [a public Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/76404742) in which this option is requested. Feel free to star it in order to receive updates, and also add a comment of your own in order to explain your use case and highlight the usability of this option.

As an alternative (which may not work for you), you would still be able to [list all tables in a dataset](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#listing_tables_in_a_dataset) and then filter by label on the client side, although in that case the client would be retrieving all the tables, obviously.

---

***UPDATE:***

Also, I have been able to find [this other public Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35906063) in which the *INFORMATION_SCHEMA* feature is announced, also with the possibility to request access to the Alpha release of this functionality.

Your project needs to be whitelisted in order to be able to use it. However, once you get the access (or the public is launched into public beta / GA), you should be able to list tables using a query like:

```
CREATE TABLE
  [DATASET].[TABLE]
OPTIONS (labels = [('key1', 'value1'), ('key2', 'value2')])
AS SELECT 1 AS x, 'foo' AS y;

SELECT
  table_name
FROM
  [DATASET].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_OPTIONS
WHERE
  option_name = 'labels'
  AND option_value LIKE '%key2%'
```

Please note that this feature is still in its [Alpha release](https://cloud.google.com/terms/launch-stages) and therefore it is subject to changes in the future.